# Request routing and identifying resource requests from web pages

Tags: http, browser, http-headers, meta-tags, haproxy

We need to route requests based on url but for the page resources (images, js, css, ajax, etc) the url may not be enough to distinguish where to route the requests, so maybe an HTTP Header could be used.

Is there a way to make the browser add a specific header in every resource request of a page?
Maybe a meta tag (or a server side header) that would ensure the browser would include this header with every request in that page?
We thought about using a cookie, but this may change when the user has more than one browser tab open.

**Edit:**
Adding a bit more detail for clarification.
Let's say I know all requests to "/banana/*" should be routed to node1, app1, and then all others fall back to node2, app2.
   https://domain.com/banana/index -> node1
   https://domain.com/orange/aaa -> node2

Then banana/index contains a reference to the following image:
   https://domain.com/images/banana.jpg -> should route to node1
And orange/aaa contains a reference to the following image:
   https://domain.com/images/orange.jpg -> should route to node2

Both app1 and app2 have a directory named "images" (with different files in them) and all references to the images are done with absolute paths like `<img src="/images/banana.jpg"/>`

Comment: Could we use the Referer header?

Comment: How is possible that *"the url may not be enough to distinguish where to route the requests"*?  That doesn't really seem to add up.

Comment: This is because 2 different apps use similar URLs for the images which is "/images/*" with root absolute paths, and likewise for other resources.

Comment: Is the `Host:` header also the same?  Otherwise, it sounds like you mean "path" or "uri" rather than "url."  A url should always be unambiguous.

Comment: Yes, The `Host:` header is the same. Looking at the resource requests that Chrome sends, looks like the `Referer:` always has the original document URL. So this could be used, but then the problem is how do we distinguish resource requests from document requests, because the `Referer:` will also be set when navigating from app1 to app2.